# Upper bounds for a binomial coefficient

Tags: algorithm-analysis, runtime-analysis, big-o-notation

I have an algorithm with worst-case time complexity in  $\mathcal O (\binom{k}{p-1})$, where $k$ is a parameter and $p$ is the input size of that algorithm. I further have determined that $p-1 \leq k $.

I need an argument which shows that the runtime complexity is solely a function of its parameter $k$, i.e. that the input size $p$ does not matter for runtime complexity.

My own argument goes as follows:

$$ \binom{k}{p-1} = \frac{k!}{(p-1)!(k-(p-1))!} \leq k!$$
Where the first equality follows from the definition of the binomial coefficient and the second inequality follows from the observation that both  $(p-1)!$ and $(k-(p-1))!$ are greater than or equal to $1$.

Thus the algorithm runs in $\mathcal O (k!)$, which is a not a function of $p$ as required.

Is this argument correct or am I missing something?
Maybe I am overcomplicating things and there is a faster / better argument?

Comment: "I need an argument which shows that the runtime complexity is solely a function of its parameter , i.e. that the input size  does not matter for runtime complexity.". Actually, it isn't quite true (for instance the *exact* complexity could be equal to $k\choose p-1$, which depends on $p$). What you've shown is that you can upper bound (asymptotically) the runtime by a function of $k$ alone.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The argument looks correct. Also notice that you can get a better (but still loose) upper bound as follows:

$$
\binom{k}{p-1} \le \sum_{i=0}^{k} \binom{k}{i} = 2^k
$$

Where the equality $\sum_{i=0}^{k} \binom{k}{i} = 2^k$ follows from the fact that the summation on the left is counting the number of possible subsets of a set with $k$ elements, grouped by cardinality: the $i$-th term of the sum (for $i=0, \dots, k$) is the number of subsets with exactly $i$ elements.

Also, using [Stirling's approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation) and assuming that $k$ is even (this is just for convenience, if it's not you can consider $k+1$ instead to get the same asymptotic bound):

$$
\binom{k}{p-1}  \le \binom{k}{k/2} = O\left( \frac{ (k/e)^k \sqrt{k} }{ k (k/2e)^k } \right) =
O\left(\frac{2^k}{\sqrt{k}} \right).
$$

Comment: Right, so the righthand side of the inequality is effectively the size of the power set and the lefthand part must definitely be smaller than that since it's only a subset of the powerset. Did I get that right?

But my solution is right in principle?

Comment: Yes. Your solution is also right.

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 3):

There are well known inequalities:
$$\frac{n^k}{k^k}\leqslant \binom{n}{k}\leqslant \frac{n^k}{k!}$$

Comment: See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient#Bounds_and_asymptotic_formulas